# SFML Particle system architecture

Tags: c++, templates, sfml

I'm currently implementing a 2D particle system with c++ and SFML

I've found this nice [post](http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/articles/article1982.html) to inspire me in building a generic system. Now comes the rendering code and I ask for some advises on the different choices that I have.

In SFML tutorials, a [particle system](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-vertex-array.php#example-particle-system) is shown as an example of a SFML entity. In this case, the particle system embeds vertex array and other rendering needs. This also implies inheritance and the design pattern of the tutorial is made to avoid inheritance. I will need inheritance to build an SFML entity but where should it be ?

So what's the best choice to implement the rendering solution ?

1. Keep straight to the SFML example and just adding a `RenderPolicy` to the list of policy and texture information to particle:

   ```
   template < class Particle , class RenderPolicy, class OtherPolicies >
   ParticleSystem : public sf::Drawable, sf::Transformable {
       // implement the virtual function
       ...
   void update(){
       RenderPolicy(Particles,VertexArray) // here the render policy update render info
   }
   // hold the VertexArray for the Particles
   ...
   }; // ParticleSystem
   ```
2. Create a Renderer for particle System as an SFML entity

   ```
   template< class ParticleSystem , class RenderPolicy >
   ParticleSystemRenderer : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable {
       // will use ParticleSystem array to build VertexArray
       // will hold texture information and other needs
   }
   ```
3. Add (or replace color policy) a RenderPolicy to the ParticleSystem that is a SFML entity

   ```
   template< class Particle >
   class RenderPolicy : public sf::Transformable , public sf::Drawable {
       // hold vertex array, texture and drawing routine
    ...
   }
   ```
4. Another idea because all of these are bad ?

I think that the best solution is the third one but some advises or opinions are welcomed
Thanks all, hope the post is understanding ;)

Answer (score 2):

A particle system renderer is usually a very specific and optimized piece of code. Usually, it  does some heavily optimized GPU rendering which means that I would most likely avoid the pre defined SFML primitives entirely and use opengl direclty.

That said, if you want to use the existing primitives they would have to be the base class of the Particle class. At least the  sf::Transformable should be the base class of each particle, as each particle should have it's own position, rotation etc.

Usually I think it's a good idea to also inherit the particle system class from the particle class so that i.e. one particle system can emit other particle systems for more complex effects (i.e. the explosion particle system could emit smoke particle systems).

Also, the policy based approach is overkill for 99% of the time and just increases the implementation complexity. I tried it a lot of times and it was never worth it.
In my experience inheritance is the better way to decouple rendering from the particle system, as it does not make every particlesystem a different type. I.e. to stick with the explosion example: Usually you want to keep track of all particle systems that need to be rendered in one place, so they need to at least share a base type and virtual interface so that they can be stored and processed in one place, so if you had a different rendering scheme for the smoke and the flames, you would still i.e. save all the particle systems that need to be rendered in one `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyParticleSystem>>`. If each particle system is a separate type, just beacause it's rendered differently, that won't work.

Comment: thx for your advice and experience sharing, I will think about that and review a bit the architecture. The management complexity of several particle system with multiple policy is clearly increased and I must think to this also